# UV image size affecting how the UV dimensions are shown

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I don't know if it is a dumb question but it bothering me for some time.

I create my 3D clothes at marvelous designer and when I import it to Blender the UV map is perfect in square size.

But for me to make it work in the game that they're made for, I need to make the UV image size at 2048x4096.
When I establish the correct size, the UV stretch, and then I currently edit the scale manually.

I want to know if has some way that I can preserve the original UV size/scale from the square image when I change the image size to 2048x4096? So I don't need to change it manually, as the texture is often not perfect.

I actually using Blender 2.79

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to export a non-square UV map?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157259/is-there-a-way-to-export-a-non-square-uv-map)

Comment: Not exactly. I've found another similar question, that does not solve it all, math is not my forte, but I can work with it. But would be great if I could just freeze the UV size not changing when I change the image size.
The one I've found: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5793/how-to-disable-the-automatic-uv-stretching-after-an-image-size-is-changed

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66727/whats-the-meaning-of-0-to-1-space-in-uv/66732#66732